# Execute async task after a certain time not working in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an application where I need to update my activity text boxes through a web service. It's working well. I wanted to check the update from web service after executing. So I created a timer inside asynctask calling method. My async task class is in seperate class. But my async task was not working.. No errors. Please help me to fix this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private View chart;
private Button btnChart;

Context context;
Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   callAsynchronousTask();
}

      //Calling AsynchronoustTask
  public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            ProductSummary ps = new ProductSummary(context,activity);
                            ps.new GetSummary().execute();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 40000);
    }
```

Product Summary Class

```
 public class ProductSummary {
    private static String url = "http://localhost/contacts.asmx";

private Context context;
Activity activity;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

public ProductSummary(Context context,Activity activity){

    this.context = context;
    this.activity=activity;
}
public class GetSummary extends AsyncTask<String, String,HashMap<String, String>> {
    //Other codes were written here.
    }
```

Comment: 1. You are leaking context as far as I can see at first glance. 2. Why not use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) ? Or for delayed execution a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: @Fidor- Thank you very much for commenting. I' m a beginner in Android and Java. I'm using Asynctask . Did I use it wrong?

Comment: What makes you think you are using it? You are using a Timer that posts to a Handler ... where did you copy this pattern from?

Comment: @Fildor- in product summary class I'm fetching data from web service through asynctask. I didn't write those code here.

Comment: Oh, I see ... I'll have a look again.

Comment: @Fildor- Yes, if you can please give me a support.